# How to generate dynamic local dir for incoming file depending upon file name in spring integration for SFTP adaptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp

I have following configuration in my sftp inbound adaptor

```
  <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
                                      channel="sftpInboundChannel"
                                      session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                      filename-pattern="*.DONE"
                                      remote-directory="/C:/Users/Desktop"                                       
                                      local-directory="D:\Documents1"
                                      auto-create-local-directory="false"
                                      local-filename-generator-expression="#this"
                                      delete-remote-files="false" >
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" task-executor="executor"/>
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I want to generate dynamic local directory for incoming file depending upon file name. Like  test123.Done is the file name then i have to put that file in my local dir D:\Documents1\test123\test123.Done likewise. 
So how to generate dynamic path for local-directory="" in my sftp in inbound adaptor ???

Comment: Share your code what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the inbound adapter for that.

You can use [outbound gateways](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) to do that; use one to get a list (`ls`) of the remote directory and a second one to fetch (`get`) each file - it takes a local directory expression and a local filename generator expression.

The [SFTP sample uses gateways to list, get, and remove remote files](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/sftp).

Comment: I got your answer @Gary and it's working properly when implemented.

Comment: @inj3ct0r  can you share samples, I am stuck here